# What is off-topic for the DevOps

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Borrowed from [Web Apps meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-off-topic-for-the-web-apps-site)

I would like this post to be a compilation for the FAQ of what is off-topic for this site. With the purpose to prevent a lot of discussion early on, about what we do or don't want to see. Off course, the community has to decide what it should be, but it does make a difference if the early examples leave out things we would want to be off-topic!

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because scoping problems should be conducted in the face of actual questions that have been asked rather than creating a lot of hypothetical rules that haven't shown to be a problem at all.

Comment: @RobertCartaino But wouldn't closed questions dissapear in a rather short time? Wouldn't this question be more valuable long-term by its answer?

Comment: @DanCornilescu As far as I know the roomba doesn't remove question with positivily scored answers. [related post on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Comment: (drive by wit) funny that the question about off topic would be off topic...

Answer (score 17):

**Don't anticipate problems.**

This site is only 45 minutes old and we've already started a thread to decide what posts should be closed here.

I can understand the desire to get to work trying to figure out the entire scope of this site in one exhaustive thread, but as a general rule for building a new community, it is typically better to wait for problems to become invasive in actual practice before we start actively seeking to create a lot of rules discussions around hypothetical situations of how people are going to do this site wrong.

If you see a problem that is concerning for you on the actual site, by all means, raise it here. But it is simply waaaay too early for an all-encompassing *"what does **not** belong here"* thread when no actual problems have been observed on the site itself. It's just not a great way to build a new community.

**That is why I closed this thread.**

Comment: I fully agree, just answered as per the talk at the proposal time for general  guidance ;)

Answer (score 6):

I assume I can extract from my [answer on Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22032/144352):

While a question is on topic here or not would be quite easy to guess, for how I see it it would be question about near anything as long as it's related to one of:

- Automation/orchestration in a wide range (all tools, from MesoSphere/Consul to .cmd files IMHO)
- Continuous integration
- Integration testing
- Unit testing of automation scripts
- Configuration management

Out of this, it will probably best suited to one StackOverflow, SuperUser, etc.

In fact the on-topic here are all the questions on a razor blade on StackOverflow or SuperUser as they involve programming and computer management (mainly server, but I won't block workstations questions)

Comment: So far most of my questions about "culture" and "affecting change" have been closed as being too broad. Not that I mind, but where do those questions belong to? :/

Comment: They've been closed because they are too broad, that doesn't mean off-topic. You should try to find a way to turn them into a focused area so it can be answered without writing a novel :) Happy to discuss it in chat.